# Flutter applying shadows to CustomPainted widget

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow

### Introduction

I draw a custom Tab-bar using Flutter's CustomPaint Widget it looks like this: 
  [image: Shape Image]

In Addition, this is the code I used to draw the widget :

```
class TabBarPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color paintColor = Colors.redAccent 
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    /// the thing that I called as a deleter circle is an imaginary circle that I used to delete a semicircle from my rectangular shape

    var diameter = 80; /// X value is the diameter(R) of the deleter circle;
    double topSpace = 2;
    double startCurve = (size.width-diameter)/2; /// Start point of the curve
    double endCurve = startCurve+diameter; // End Point of the curve


     /// Some math about my cubic bezier curve
    double xValueInset = diameter * 0.05; 
    double yValueOffset = (diameter/2) * 4.0 / 3.0; 

    Path path = Path();

    Paint paint = Paint();

    /// Points to make a semicircle approximation using Bezier Curve
    var firstendPoint = new Offset(endCurve, topSpace);
    var controlPoint1  = new Offset(startCurve+xValueInset,yValueOffset+topSpace);
    var controlPoint2  = new Offset((diameter-xValueInset)+startCurve,yValueOffset+topSpace);

    //! Start sketching Shape
    path.moveTo(0.0,topSpace);
    path.lineTo(startCurve, topSpace);
    path.cubicTo(controlPoint1.dx, controlPoint1.dy,
    controlPoint2.dx, controlPoint2.dy,
    firstendPoint.dx, firstendPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(size.width, topSpace);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.close();
    //! End sketching Shape

    paint.color = paintColor;

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TabBarPainter oldDelegate) =>  oldDelegate != this;
}
```

### Experimenting

I want to apply a shodow on my CustomDrawen Shape so I tried 2 methods:

First Method: I used a classical container and boxshadow to shadow it and it looked like this: 
   [image: Shape Image shadow Applied]
 I used the following code :

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.30),
        blurRadius: 3,
        ffset: new Offset(0, -3)
      )
    ]
  ),
  child: CustomPaint(           
    painter: TabBarPainter(),
  ),
```

Second Method : I drew a similar black colored(opacity(0.15)) shape
  and it looked like this:

[image: Shape with a sub shape approximating the shadow]

I added the following code to my CustomPainter in order to draw this shape:

```
final Color shadowColor = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15);

Path shadowPath = Path();
Paint shadowPaint = Paint();

/// Points to make a semicircle approximation using Bezier Curve

var shadowfirstendPoint = new Offset(endCurve-topSpace, 0.0);
var shadowcontrolPoint1  = new Offset(startCurve+xValueInset+topSpace,yValueOffset);
var shadowcontrolPoint2  = new Offset((diameter-xValueInset)+startCurve-topSpace,yValueOffset);

//! Start sketching Shadow   
shadowPath.lineTo(startCurve+topSpace, 0.0);
shadowPath.cubicTo(shadowcontrolPoint1.dx, shadowcontrolPoint1.dy,
shadowcontrolPoint2.dx, shadowcontrolPoint2.dy,
shadowfirstendPoint.dx, shadowfirstendPoint.dy);
shadowPath.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
shadowPath.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
shadowPath.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
shadowPath.close();

//! End Sketching Shadow
shadowPaint.color = shadowColor;
canvas.drawPath(shadowPath, shadowPaint);
```

### Problem

In the first method, blank area - at the top center of widget - was filled with shadow

In the second method, shadow was not realistic because even though it had low opacity, it did not had a blur and I could not find a method to make it blurred

### Conclusion

I need another way to properly shadow my widget or add blur to my shadow-like custom drawn shape

Since flutter is doing this to every type of widget they created, it seems possible

I would be thankful to any kind of helper

Regards

Comment: use drawShadow method to draw a shadow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned, there is a method of canvas called drawShadow

so changing my drawing method for my shadowPath to :

```
canvas.drawShadow(shadowPath, Colors.black, 2.0, true);
```

Will solve the problem and the output will be something like this :
 [image: Final Image]

Thanks for everyone !!

Answer (score 11):

An easier way I found was to offset the path

```dart
canvas.drawShadow(path.shift(Offset(0, -5)), Colors.black, 2.0, true);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Elevation can be set to customize spread